# Laravel Auth in error pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When a user is logged into my application, there is a dropdown in the navigation to access administration. However, when a user stumbles across an error page (404, for instance) it doesn't show them being logged in. Instead it shows "Login". Why is this?

Here's my code.

```
@if (Auth::check())

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> {{ Auth::user()->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/dashboard"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/logout"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

@else

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/login"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Login</a</li>
    </ul>

@endif
```

Comment: Can you dump the session in your 404 page? What do you see?

Comment: Looks like the session is empty inside of error pages, but nowhere else.

Comment: Apparently, this is not an isolated problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142168/laravel-5-sessions-on-404-route

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11653

Comment: Meh. I'll just add `StartSession` to the global middlewares.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Laravel only starts the session where it sees appropriate (which isn't a 404 page) as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556005/daniel) pointed out: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11653.

To combat this (as the navigation bar is site-wide, including 404 pages) I added the `StartSession` class to the global middlwares.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class
];
```

Now becomes...

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
];
```

Comment: This works but if you have an API layer this is not a solution as it will add sessions to your stateless API.