# Laravel check if user is loggedin always returns false in a 404 error blade file

Tags: php, laravel

Am creating a custom 404 error file so i have

in `app/Exception/handler`

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
      {
      if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
       return response()->view('errors.404', [], 200);
      }
       return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Now the file  404.blade.php

```
   @if (Auth::check())
      <h1>You are loggedin 

   @else

    <h1>You arent loggedin //this is always executed

   @endif
```

When i place the above code in any other blade file it works

What could be wrong?

Comment: updated but still fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel only starts sessions if a route is matched and has the `web` middleware applied. As your 404 pages don't *have* a route, this means they don't have session data.

You have a couple approaches.

- [Move the session middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142168/laravel-5-sessions-on-404-route) into the "all requests" `$middleware` section instead of just the "web" section. This may have side-effects...
- If you're in Laravel 5.5.5 or higher, there's [new functionality](https://twitter.com/themsaid/status/910135205989625856) called `Route::fallback` that will allow you to easily have sessions enabled there.

Comment: since am also using api routes option 1 may not be good ill try option 2