# Unable to access sessions in Laravel app\Exceptions\Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel, exception, handler

I'm trying to display 404 page based upon user login, for which I'm trying to get the logged in user id from sessions.

But session `session()->all()` always returns empty array and also `auth()->id();` & `Auth::id();` are also empty value.

Comment: try `Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: getting `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Comment: are you logged in?? are you trying to access this after login??

Comment: yes, I'm logged in I can access sessions for normal urls but for 404 Exception it is empty

Comment: how you get authenticated user in controller??

Comment: I'm first getting the user id from sessions then using eloquent query to get user details

Comment: show us your controller code where this works for you

Comment: That is a normal controller with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;` and I'm accessing this user id as `Session::get('portal.user.id')`
but same thing I'm unable to access in Handler.php file

Comment: did you try with `dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::all())` in handler

Comment: Show us the full code. Just tried with the session('key') and it worked.

Comment: Maybe the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142168/laravel-5-sessions-on-404-route) can help you. The problem is that Laravel sessions are not default started on error pages as they are on most other pages inside your web middleware.

Comment: I have solved the issue in the same solution and then saw your comment :).. Any way thank you so much @milo526 this solved my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in `app/Http/Kernel.php` the `protected $middleware` array doesn't have the middleware for the session.

What you can do is to move the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` middleware from the `web` middlware group to the global `$middleware` array.

Comment: Thank you @Lloople

Comment: Doesn't work for me..