# Laravel redirecting back using withErrors but can't display error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

So I have a user interface where users can upload videos. I have a validation rule to prevent too big videos. But if the video is even bigger than the post_max_size is giving an error screen before reaching the formrequest class, and I don't want that. I just want to inform the user, that ,,Hello, this video is too big" . So I went to my Handler.php class and made changes to the render function like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'Too big file']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

It returns me back to the previous url but fails to inform about error, and that's my problem.

I tried

```
@error('message')
```

and

```
 @foreach($errors as $error)
        {{$error}}
 @endforeach
```

even

```
session->get('message');
```

but non of these helped, it seems my error message is not there. I would be happy to have any advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying the Error Messages in Laravel after being Redirected from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732821/displaying-the-error-messages-in-laravel-after-being-redirected-from-controller)

Comment: Try `with('error', 'Something')` the `withErrors` I think requires a specific kind of object to work with.

Comment: @benlumley Not really, or I don't get it. According to Laravel documentation, withErrors function can take array as function parameter, that's why I made it like that. But I can't access this message or its maybe not there

Comment: @apokryfos I tried your solution, I've dd-ed my session also in my controller, but cant find the error data :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I couldn't access the session from Handler.php.

Here is a solution for the problem: [Unable to access sessions in Laravel app\Exceptions\Handler.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397625/unable-to-access-sessions-in-laravel-app-exceptions-handler-php)

But I did it another way. I've added a nullable parameter to my route, and when redirecting -if it's not already there-, I've added the error, passed it to my blade, and it works now, but note that this wont work for every occurence for an error, only on the interface / interfaces where you add this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`withErrors` already contain `error` and all you have to do is put a message only

```
return back()->withError('Too big file');
```

and display in blade like

```
session('error')
```

**Edited**
my working data

```
return redirect()->back()->withError('Data is used in another page, delete is not possibe!');
```

and in blade file

```
@if (Session('error'))
  <p class="text-danger">{{ session('error') }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: oh still include `[]`, remove the bracket and also remove `s` in errors try again.. also updated my answer

Comment: I've copy pasted this, but no luck :(

Comment: Well, it's at the bottom of a component file below the form. If I write any test text there it's showing. Like: (S/o doesnt allow the at)

<div class="form-block">
 if(some condition)
        ...my form
    endif
        if (Session('error'))
            <p class="text-danger">{{ session('error') }}</p>
        endif
</div>